# Em Java teria como uma variável receber uma função assim como no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, expressões-lambda

Exemplo:

```
var x = function (a, b) {
           return a * b 
        };
```

Teria como? Ou é uma característica do JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em Java 8 pode usar a sintaxe de *lambda*. Antes disso só criando *functors*, que não é exatamente a mesma coisa, mas dá resultado parecido.

```
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> x = (a, b) -> a * b;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Lambda.java).

Claro que difere na questão de que tudo é tipado, mas é simples assim.

Tem outras formas de declarar conforme a necessidade e número de argumentos. Sem um contexto maior não sei se esta é a melhor forma para o caso. [Veja mais opções](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html).

Não sei te dizer se em Java 15 ou 16 pode usar `var` no lugar do tipo (acho que não, precisa pesquisar).

Comment: Para funções com 2 argumentos somente.

Comment: Legal! Isso no java poderia ser eficiente em qual contexto Maniero ?

Comment: Só um exemplo, por favor.

Comment: Esta é a forma para 2 argumentos. Tem para um e deve ter para mais, mas em Java eu não conheço os mecanismo exatos, precisaria pesquisar. Não é eficiência, pelo contrário, isto é menos eficiente porque tem [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) extra. Isto é usado para parametrizar ações em códigos que você sabe quase tudo o que fazer, mas tem um ponto que o consumidor é que deve definir o que executar. É igual ao JS.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Maniero!!!

Answer (score -1):

Não... o mais próximo seria:

```
metodoTeste(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
});
```

ou

```
metodoTeste(() -> System.out.println("Hello"));
```